# Pasing link with Python , BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Cant get the link from this element:

```
<h3 class="proposition_name">
  <a href="/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1834871.html">
     <strong>Jeep Grand Cherokee 2019</strong>
  </a>
</h3>
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-jeep/'
HEADERS={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36','accept':'*/*'}
def get_html(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS,params=params)
    return r
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    itemsdiv = soup.findAll('div', class_='proposition') #class that contains the upper element
    cars = []

    for itemdiv in itemsdiv:
        cars.append({
            'title': itemdiv.find('h3',class_='proposition_name').get_text(strip=True),
        })
        print(itemdiv.find('a',href_='proposition_area').get_text())#here i am trying to get the link
    print(cars)


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code==200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

**What i have tried:**

1)`print(itemdiv.find('a',href_='proposition_area').get_text())# gettin none`

2)Created another item with param 'a'

```
itemsa = soup.findAll('a', class_='proposition')
```

and then another for loop

```
for itema in itemsa:
    print(itema.get('href'))
```

3) Printed every item as text

```
for itemdiv in itemsdiv:
    cars.append({
        'title': itemdiv.find('h3',class_='proposition_name').get_text(strip=True),
    })
    print(itemdiv.get_text())
```

but there were no links in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for x in soup.find_all("h3", attrs={"class":"proposition_name"}):
    print("{} , {}".format(x.find("a")['href'], x.text))
```

**Output**

```
/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1834871.html ,  Jeep Grand Cherokee 2019
/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1838297.html ,  Jeep Grand Cherokee 2018
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prettytable import PrettyTable


p = PrettyTable()
p.field_names = ["Name", "Url"]


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.select_one("div#searchResult").select("h3.proposition_name")
    for tar in target:
        p.add_row([tar.a.get_text(strip=True), f"{url[:20]}{tar.a['href']}"])
    print(p)


main("https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-jeep/")
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           Name           |                                Url                                 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Jeep Grand Cherokee 2019 | https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1834871.html |
| Jeep Grand Cherokee 2018 | https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1838297.html |
| Jeep Grand Cherokee 2019 | https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1836192.html |
|    Jeep Compass 2019     |    https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-compass-1838186.html     |
|    Jeep Renegade 2019    |    https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-renegade-1838198.html    |
|    Jeep Wrangler 2018    |    https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1838190.html    |
|    Jeep Compass 2019     |    https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-compass-1838277.html     |
|    Jeep Wrangler 2017    |    https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1838228.html    |
| Jeep Grand Cherokee 2020 | https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1834293.html |
| Jeep Grand Cherokee 2018 | https://auto.ria.com/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1810691.html |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

global comps

```
comps = []
for item in items:
    comps.append({ 'title': item.find('h3', class_='proposition_name').get_text(strip = True),
                   'price': item.find('div', class_='proposition_price').get_text(strip=True),
                   'city': item.find('div', class_='proposition_region grey size13').get_text(strip=True),
                   'link': item.find("h3", attrs={"class": "proposition_name"}).a.get('href')
                   })
    print(comps)
```